# Run GCC on Bash on Windows 10 with C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run `gcc` on `bash` with `C#` or `C++` so I can make a little IDE for it. I tried to run gcc with cmd: `bash gcc --version` (--version is just a example) but it shows the error: `/usr/bin/gcc: /usr/bin/gcc: Can't run the file`

So i guess i need a specific command in `C#` or `C++`? Or can i somehow run `gcc` on `bash` directly?

Comment: You didn't mention C in your title or question, so why the C language tab?  After all, C, C# and C++ are all *different* languages.

Comment: You may want to search the internet for "MinGW Windows".  The `Mingw` is a GNU compiler that runs on Windows platforms.

Comment: @Thomas: I guess he wants to compile C code from a development environment written in C# or C++.  If that's true, the `c` tag doesn't belong.

Comment: By "Bash on Windows" are you talking the User Mode Ubuntu environment (real Linux syscalls going to Windows Subsystem for Linux instead of a Linux kernel) on later updates of Windows 10?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what steps you have performed so far? Install `bash` and `gcc` on your Windows 10, along with the "Linux compatibility package", or something else?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes i am talking about the Windows Subsystem for Linux running on the windows kernel

Comment: @MatsPetersson I installed bash and gcc on Windows 10, but i don't think i installed the Linux compatibility package...

Comment: I mean WSL for "Linux compatibility package".

Comment: U can use VirtualBox

Comment: @MatsPetersson I installed the WSL so yes^^

Comment: @viveknuna I want to be able to run gcc on bash over a C# or C++ application. Using VirtualBox wouldn't help at all because i can already use bash on windows but without the ability to launch it from a C# or C++ application.

Comment: CL works for C#

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to ensure you've got gcc installed in Bash before you can invoke it from Bash or from Windows.

An easy way to do this is to install `build-essential` pseudo-package which will bring in GCC/G++ and a host of other commonly required dev tools, libs, etc:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Once you've done this, run `gcc --version` from within Bash to make sure it's reachable:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now you should be able to invoke gcc from cmd/PowerShell/CreateProcess/Process.Create()/etc:

```
C:\> bash -c "gcc --version"
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

HTH

Comment: I had a similar problem. I didn't want to do is apt because I already had a version of gcc's installed with min GW then I wanted to minimize installations. But, from what you're saying, Beth has to have its own version of GCC?

Comment: While you can invoke gcc installed in Windows from within a Linux instance, you'll likely want to invoke the real Linux gcc when working in Linux and building a Linux app. If so, install via apt so you're up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing `Cygwin` on your system

The `bash` shell is one of many supported by `Cygwin`

Comment: Native Linux executables should work in Windows 10, with the right support installed.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I can run gcc in the wsl bash but i can't run gcc like a normal windows app. So i need a way to launch it in C# or C++ like System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("bash.exe", "gcc --version"); in C#.

Comment: Which `bash` does "bash.exe" start - a Windows version, or the WSL one?

Comment: Indirectly yes. The Windows bash.exe calls the Linux subsystem handler which then launches the Linux bash. You will have two processes running then, bash.exe and bash (and init, actually).

Comment: And for launching wsl applications, use `c:\windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c "the command you want"`